# Handshake failure connecting to mongodb atlas due missing public key

Tags: java, mongodb, connection, public-key

I try to connect to mongodb atlas with my java client. The connection didn't succeed because there is an SSL error. In the logfiles the following text occurs:

> SSL HANDSHAKE FAILURE:  A signer with SubjectDN [CN=*.mk3fd.mongodb.net] was sent from the host. The extended error message from the SSL handshake exception is: [PKIX path building failed:
> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target].

Is there a possibility to download the public key from mk3fd.mongodb.net connection to add it to my jav keystore or is there another solution to connect from java to mongod atlas?

nb.  connection to MongoDB Atlas with MongoDB Compass is working fine.

Comment: Try https://lonesysadmin.net/2018/11/26/retrieve-an-ssl-certificate-from-a-server-with-openssl/

Comment: Good suggestion. I tried it but there were other certificates in the call then requested bij java. Will try futher to the sollution

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to the problem.

With openssl you can get all the keys. I used the next two command and recieved three different certificates

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -servername mydatabase_shard.mk3fd.mongodb.net:27017 -connect mydatabase_shard.mk3fd.mongodb.net:27017 < /dev/null
```

and

```
openssl s_client -connect mydatabase_shard.mk3fd.mongodb.net:27017 < /dev/null
```

The three retrieved certificates are placed in a jks keystore. This keystore is used for getting the connection to the shared MongoDB cluster It works like a charm